# case insensitive NSPredicate with single result in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Here is my current NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UPC==%@ OR ItemID==%@", aUPCCode,aUPCCode];
```

How can I make this case insensitive?

And I do not want to do any partial matching.

Example if they enter 123 for aUPCCode I do not want to get 123, 123a, 123b, 123c, ect.  I would only want an exact match.

I thought about doing this but it seems a little ridiculous:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UPC==%@ OR ItemID==%@ OR UPC==%@ OR ItemID==%@ OR UPC==%@ OR ItemID==%@", aUPCCode,aUPCCode,[ aUPCCode lowercaseString] ,[aUPCCode lowercaseString], [aUPCCode uppercaseString],[aUPCCode uppercaseString]];
```

Comment: Clarification: You say, " if they enter 123 for aUPCCode I do not want to get 123..." That doesn't make any sense. Is that a typo. Also, you seem to be implying that your current predict is "greedy" test that matches any value that starts with `123`. Is that the case?

Comment: What type of persistent store are you using?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> This answer is from 2011, if you are using Swift check [Harjot Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387590/515275).

As Dave DeLong said, you can use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UPC ==[c] %@ OR ItemID ==[c] %@", aUPCCode,aUPCCode];
```

**Edit**:

Use `==[c]` instead of `==[cd]` or you get accents too (`abcd == àbcd`).

Answer (score 21):

As Sinetris said, the above works in Objective-C.

It works for case-insensitive. Fetches all results which have the "example" string value in it.

**Update Swift 4.0/5.0**

```
let predicateIsNumber = NSPredicate(format: "keywordContactNo contains[c] %@", example!)
```

---

Hope it helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UPC MATCHES[cd] %@ OR ItemID MATCHES[cd] %@",aUPCCode,aUPCCode];
```

Comment: `MATCHES` is an unnecessary addition.  You can do `UPC ==[cd] %@...`